# Setting LiveCard layout views and strings using the R class

Tags: java, android, android-layout

I'm trying to register the ids for specific view attributes in the R class, but when I update the R class, the android sdk is rejecting the values and resetting them automatically.

```
 mLiveCardView.setTextViewText(R.id.homeTeamNameTextView, getString(R.id.home_team));

                mLiveCardView.setTextViewText(R.id.awayTeamNameTextView, getString(R.id.home_team));
                mLiveCardView.setTextViewText(R.id.footer_text, getString(R.id.game_quarter));
```

What is the correct way to create and set the id's in the R class? Also which R class is LiveCard suppose to use? Lastly, is there a way to set the Start_STICKY integer or is it always some value?

```
@Override
        public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {

            //TimelineManager tm = new TimelineManager();

            if(mLiveCard == null){
                RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(),
                         R.layout.livecard_view);
                mLiveCard.setViews(views);

//            // Set up initial RemoteViews values
                homeScore = 0;
                awayScore = 0;
                mLiveCardView.setTextViewText(R.id.homeTeamNameTextView, getString(R.id.home_team));

                mLiveCardView.setTextViewText(R.id.awayTeamNameTextView, getString(R.id.home_team));
                mLiveCardView.setTextViewText(R.id.footer_text, getString(R.id.game_quarter));


                // Set up the live card's action with a pending intent
                // to show a menu when tapped
                Intent menuIntent = new Intent(this, NavigateViewActivity.class);
                menuIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK |
                    Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK);
                mLiveCard.setAction(PendingIntent.getActivity(
                    this, 0, menuIntent, 0));

                // Publish the live card
                mLiveCard.publish(PublishMode.REVEAL);

                // Queue the update text runnable
                mHandler.post(mUpdateLiveCardRunnable);
            }
            return START_STICKY;
```

Answer (score 0):

`R` class is automatically generated by `android aapt` which basically contains the `numerical representation` of all the resource IDs for all the resources in your `res` directory, which means you cannot edit the `R` class yourself.
If you want to create new resource, instead of editing your `R` class, modify the correct `resource` file and `android` automatically generated the `R` class.

See [link](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/accessing-resources.html)